# How can i find certain div by class name from dynamic php data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to find a class name from dynamically outputted data from query.
i want to find class ".usersesg" in the given scenario:

```
var file = '<?php echo $fileContent[0]->Content; ?>';
//alert(file);

var find = file.find(".userdesg").val();
console.log(find);
```

using alert in the above code i get all the content in the file variable.
and i get the following error with the above code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: file.find is not a function
```

Comment: Strings do not have a `.find` method

Comment: @CertainPerformance then considering the situation suggest something that solves this please.

Comment: What is the significance of the `file` string?

Comment: Assuming it is HTML: Add it to a `div`and use `querySelector` on it. Assuming it is XML: Use `DOMParser`.

Comment: Also if the file has any breaklines or single quotes, the var will have invalid content

Comment: alert on file variable gives me content with html tags. i want to get a div inside that content <div class="userdesg"></div>

Comment: @Haroon Khan: It would be better to just output what you actually need by php.

Comment: What is the status on this question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a string, not a DOM object

if the file has any breaklines or single quotes, the var will have invalid content

You MIGHT want to try this (you can set the div display to none)

```
<div id="myFile"><?php echo $fileContent[0]->Content; ?></div>
<script>
var find = $("#myFile").find(".userdesg").val();
console.log(find);
</script>
```

assuming you have loaded jQuery and that the file contains a valid HTML string that does not have random `</div>` in it

Comment: What if the string starts with `</div>`?

Comment: Yeah... Likely unlikely

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```
console.log(
    new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div class="userdesg">cucubau</div>', 'text/xml').querySelector('.userdesg').textContent
)
```